# How to handle invalid HTML generated by Summernote WYSIWYG editor

Tags: laravel, summernote

I'm using Summernote WYSIWYG editor with Laravel framework.

I noticed that many scenarios using Summernote WYSIWYG editor can to situation where lead invalid HTML code is generated. For example, user can select multiple lines including different text and even some pictures in selection. Then, if user clicks on BOLD or ITALIC, invalid HTML is generated.

My question is how you approach this problem ?

I have a function to remove `<p>...</p>` around HTML code:

```
private static function removeWrapperPTag($code)
{
    if(starts_with($code, '<p'))
    {
        $corrected = str_replace_first('<p','<div',$code);

        if(ends_with($code, '</p>'))
            return str_replace_last('</p>','</div>',$corrected);
        else if(ends_with($code, "</p>\n"))
            return str_replace_last("</p>\n",'</div>',$corrected);
    }
    return $code;
}
```

...but this is only one example, how to detect all possible scenarios which will produce invalid HTML code ?

I'm very interested to hear from you how you handle this issues...

Comment: You could use [tidy](https://php.net/tidy). That's weird, though - SummerNote should be using the browser's `contentEditable` features, which should generate valid HTML.

Comment: Looks like by invalid he means it adds  `<p>` instead of `<div>`. You could try [this solution](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/546#issuecomment-362685271), which recommends adding `$.summernote.dom.emptyPara = "<div><br/></div>";`. I can't test this right now.